# difference between .html() and .load()

Tags: jquery, html

I want to load another php or html file inside a div. Should I use `.load()` or `.html()`?
What is the difference?

Comment: Those are completely unrelated; http://api.jquery.com/load/ and http://api.jquery.com/html/

Comment: Use 'include()' of PHP?

Answer (score 8):

`.load` is a shorthand for doing an asynchronous request and putting the contents in the element you are calling this on.

`.html` is a method to put the argument to it as the contents of the element you are calling this on.

You want to use `.load`.

Comment: ```.load``` is more or less a combination of ```.post``` and ```.html```, that's why it could be confusing. The following does the same thing:

```$('#your-element').load(url, data);```

and

```$.post(url, data, function(response) {
  $('#your-element').html(response);
});```

Comment: The other answer is also useful and complements this one as fetching a remote file is the reason to use .load in this case

Answer (score 2):

There is pretty big difference. .html() cannot fetch remote file.

> [Get the HTML contents of the first element in the set of matched
>   elements or set the HTML contents of every matched element.](http://api.jquery.com/html/)

If you are intrested in other ajax methods in jQuery, I recommend documentation: http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/shorthand-methods/

Comment: I'd separate the second part of the quote or maybe even omit the first part altogether: [Set the HTML contents of each element in the set of matched elements.][2] [2]: [http://api.jquery.com/html/#html2] (I can't edit it due to "too many pending edits").